# With django-filter, is there a quick way to support all possible lookups for fields?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

`django-filter` allows you to easily declare filterable fields of a model.

For example,

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username']
```

provides an `exact` lookup for the `username` field which is equivalent to this...

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'username': ['exact']
        }
```

I'm looking for a way support all possible lookup filters given the field so that I don't have to do this:

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            "username": ["exact", "iexact", "contains", "icontains", "startswith", ..., etc.]
        }
```

Comment: in the [docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/ref/filters.html#field-name) seems like fields support ORM lookup separator, so you can try to use "username__in" to query in a list

Comment: @LinhNguyen Yes, I can. What I'm asking is if there is a way to enable ALL supported lookups without actually writing `username__in` in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the **`get_fields(...)`** class method of **`FilterSet`** class as,

```
import django_filters as filters
# If you are using DRF, import `filters` as
# from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class AnyModelFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = AnyModel
        fields = '__all__'

    @classmethod
    def get_fields(cls):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        for field_name in fields.copy():
            lookup_list = cls.Meta.model._meta.get_field(field_name).get_lookups().keys()
            fields[field_name] = lookup_list
        return fields
```

Comment: Wherefrom did you imported `filters`? how to add this class to the views?

Comment: thank you. Now, should I add `AnyModelFilter` to the views?

Comment: probably, but, it completely depends on how you are going to use it

Answer (score 2):

You can get all possible lookups of a field by [django lookup up api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/lookups/#django.db.models.lookups.RegisterLookupMixin.get_lookups)

```
lookups_list = []

lookups = User._meta.get_field("username").get_lookups()
for lookup in lookups:
    lookups_list.append(lookup)
```

result of lookups_list:

> ['exact', 'iexact', 'gt', 'gte', 'lt', 'lte', 'in', 'contains',
>   'icontains', 'startswith', 'istartswith', 'endswith', 'iendswith',
>   'range', 'isnull', 'regex', 'iregex']

So you can use it in your `FilterSet`

Answer (score 0):

```
def fields_lookups(MyModel):
    lookups = {}

    fields = [x.name for x in MyModel._meta.fields] #<=1) get all fields names
    for field in fields:
        lookups[field] = [*MyModel._meta.get_field(
            field).get_lookups().keys()]            #<=2) add each field to a `dict`and set it vlaue to the lookups
    return lookups
```

```
class StatsticsView(ItemsView):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StatisticSer

    filterset_fields = fields_lookups(MyModel) #<= ✅

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ....
    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ....
    .
    .
    .
```